# Unity Google Play Services for iOS 'TokenClient'

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have no problem in Google Play services. the thing is I can't build for Xcode because I'm using the Unity Google Play Services plugin. I don't plan on using iOS. I read that I have to put NO_GPGS on Scripting Define Symbols but it gives me this error

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TokenClient' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official github issues page (https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/689) they have fixed this issue in the latest release (released 10 hours ago as I write this) which is 0.9.25. You may need to delete the old plugin before installing this one. Just delete the Assets/GooglePlayGames folder and any lingering google files in your Assets/Editor and Assets/Plugins/Android folders. Maybe back up first as well, if you don't use source control.

The issues page used to be dormant but they seem to be actively responding to questions these days.